# Redirect url with key formula in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do this in Magento 2:

- I have my url : https://www.example.com/page/
- I'd like to add after /page a key value. Example : `/page/key1`, `/page/key2` ...
- Then I get the key value with `$this->getUrlParams()` and depending of the key value I display something different.

Getting the key value works if I do a rewrite url through Magento 2 Admin but I want to do it programmatically.

Any advice ? If you need more explanation, don't hesitate to tell me.

Thank you!

Comment: hi there, could you please be more specific about `Getting the key value works if I do a rewrite url through Magento 2 Admin but I want to do it programmatically.`?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-url-rewrites-magento-2.html
If I rewrite /page by /page/key1, I can get urlParams and use it in a variable $key = $this->getUrlParams()

Comment: ok yeah, i got that :) but how about the fact that you 'want to do it programmatically'? this can relate to the webserver level, to Magento internal redirection and url creation? which is it? where is the programmatic solution needed?

Comment: Can't really say. I'm new to backend ... I don't want to rewrite url with admin . I get my param after a post method and use it in an Array to display informations.
But when I click on one of my 3 submit buttons, I send param1, param2 or param3. I want to show it to the user (button2 click > url/param2). Is it clear? :)